# Encountering a "chunk error" when attempting to load a page in an Angular application

Tags: angular, angular-material

Description
In our Angular 12 application, we've implemented lazy loading for multiple modules. Upon building the project, the Angular CLI generates multiple JavaScript files without any reported errors.

We are currently facing an issue within our Angular 12 application. Occasionally, the application displays an error indicating that a specific chunk file has not been loaded not for all routes. This problem seems to occur for particular routes, where the corresponding JavaScript file fails to load as expected.

The situation raises a question: if a chunk file is failing to load, it might suggest that the file is unavailable on the server. However, it's worth noting that the file does indeed exist on the server. Performing a hard refresh resolves the issue temporarily. However, the inconsistency lies in the fact that after undergoing 6-7 hard refreshes, the solution might work on the 3rd refresh attempt, but the problem resurfaces upon the 4th or 5th refresh.

Despite conducting extensive research on Google, the prevailing solution for addressing the chunk error seems to be limited to performing a refresh. I'm seeking a more comprehensive and effective resolution to this issue.

[image]

Comment: The error say you that Angular try to load "seller/561-es2027.js" and the server return an html (I imagine the problem is that it's returned a 404.html error page). if Angular look for in the directory "seller" it's because you have changed the base href or a problem with your server. Take a look to the [docs](https://angular.io/guide/deployment#server-configuration). Sorry, I really don't know if this can give you any clue or not

Comment: Thank you for your response, Eliseo. I am aware that the "561-es2017.js" file is being returned as HTML. To address this, we have implemented server-level logic: if the JS file is not found, the server responds with a status code of 200 and redirects to the index page. However, I am seeking a more precise explanation. I would like to understand why our code attempts to call the missing file in the first place. This situation raises concerns that the browser might display an outdated version of the index file if the code continues to reference this missing file.

Comment: When we use "lazy loading", Angular create different bundles (that are called when the module is loaded). Your are using "outputHashing=none" in anywhere. See that are changes between Angular versions to indicate this (in some version use the angular.json, in another one is generated with hashing or not according the command line when you create the app in production..). I dont' know if it's related or not with your problem